# Magento 2 Get order total on success page?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, phtml

I'm trying to get the order total on the success page on magento 2 , I have added this code

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$totall = $order->getGrandTotal();
?>
```

But I'm getting an error when I reach the success page after I place an order, I guess the code works for magento 1 but not 2.
How can I get this working also on magento 2?

Comment: Hi @alexcr you use magento 1 command to get data.  Just put  below code to get order data in success page in magneto 2.       
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
              $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
echo "<pre>";print_r($orderData->getData());

Comment: Check this link http://www.codextblog.com/code-snippet/get-order-information-from-order-id-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Magento 2.1

The block mentioned below is now `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success`

### Magento 2.0

The only thing you can retrieve natively on this page is the order id using the `getRealOrderId()` method defined in `Magento\Checkout\Block\Success`

Thus, to get the order id you can call the following in your template:

```
$block->getRealOrderId();
```

However, I understand that's not exactly what you need.

In that case, even though **you could use the object manager directly, it is not recommended. You should use a custom module to define prefences for this block**.

In `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` you need the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Success"
                type="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Success"/>
</config>
```

Then in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout/Success.php` :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Success
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getGrandTotal()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->getLastOrderId());
        return $order->getGrandTotal();
    }
}
```

Don't forget the usual `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

As well as the `app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Once you're done and you've ran the following commands:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

You should be able to call the following in your template:

```
$block->getGrandTotal();
```

### Adding more methods

You can add the following that can be useful when tracking to the block class:

```
public function getSubtotal()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->getLastOrderId());
    return $order->getSubtotal();
}

public function getDiscountAmount()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->getLastOrderId());
    return $order->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

Then you'll be able to call the following from your template:

```
$block->getSubtotal();
$block->getDiscountAmount();
```

Comment: hi Raphel, i have take just reference from your answer.

Comment: @Rakesh I have no problem with you referencing my answer, we are here to learn and teach, it is just not fair to simply copy/paste the upvoted answer because you are downvoted. The original poster accepted your original answer, which means your answer is correct and worked for him. However, as I said in my answer and as David Manners said in the comment, it is not recommended and should be avoided whenever it's possible.

Comment: @Rakesh well I'm not responsible for upvotes and downvotes. And copy/pasting other's answers will not help you getting upvoted. Again your answer is correct for every users, it will work everywhere but it is discouraged to use the ObjectManager directly. We're here to learn and I'm sure you will try to avoid using the ObjectManager directly in your future answers

Comment: Hi Raphael, if your example doesn't work and app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout/Success.php is not rendered at all (even if I insert die() or illegal php syntax), does it mean that it is overwritten somewhere else? I run  the compile..

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga it could be. Last time I tested that was on early Magento 2.0 I haven't tried the code on latest 2.1 releases. You can use `echo get_class($block);` to check if the override works but if the block isn't rendered at all that's probably not gonna work

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism ah, yes, it is `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success` in 2.1, so I guess the structure is now Module/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Success.php

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga I'm going to update my answer thanks for that ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to function properly in 2.1.2. Leaves a blank success page.

Comment: I would like to use this in magento 2.1.8 but unfortunately it isn't working. Can someone please update this answer with correct way for 2.1.x.

Comment: This does not seem to work for Magento 2.3.X. I get the error `Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Onepage\Success::$_orderFactory in /htdocs/XXX/YYY/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Success.php on line 19`

Answer (score 7):

Just open  `Magento_Checkout/frontend/templates/success.phtml`

And put below code in File

```
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
              $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
echo "<pre>";print_r($orderData->getData());
```

In above code you will get all order data in success page.

Thanks

Comment: Citing the official documentation: 
"Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class. See usage rules."

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is an event - `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` which is fired after Checkout one page is successfully.

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php**

```
public function execute()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator')->isValid()) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
    $session->clearQuote();
    //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
        ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
    );
    return $resultPage;
}
```

As we can see, we can get the order id by using Observer. For example:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        return $this;
    }

    //.......

    $block = $this->_layout->getBlock('your_block_here');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setOrderIds($orderIds);
    }
}
```

Take a look at the google modules for more details:
**vendor/magento/module-google-adwords**
**vendor/magento/module-google-analytics**

Comment: I like the idea of using an observer, however the way you're doing it is kind of useless because there's already a method to retrieve the order id in the block (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I tried Raphaels solution but it did not work on my system (Magento 2.3.6).

I modified the Success.php like this and this solution worked for me:

```
<?php
namespace MODULE\NAME\Block\Checkout;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{

    public function getId()
    {
        $lastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();
        return $lastorderId;
    }
    
    public function getGrandTotal()
    {
        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        return $order->getGrandTotal();
    }

    public function getSubtotal()
   /** Total net value of order without taxes */
    {
    $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    return $order->getSubtotal();
    }

    public function getTaxAmount()
    {
    $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    return $order->getTaxAmount();
    }
    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magneto 2.1.x, 2.3.x and 2.4.x

Create custom module and Override  `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success`

#1 Create: `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

#2 create: `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Onepage\Success"/>
</config>
```

#2 create: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

#4 create: `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Onepage/Success.php`

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getGrandTotal()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
       $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        return $order->getGrandTotal();
    }
}
```

#5 on success page template `Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml` use

```
$block->getGrandTotal();
```

if mode production:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

else

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```