# Magento 2.1 get order grand total on success.phtml

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to get the grand total on success.phtml page so I can use it with various tracking codes for third-party vendors.

I follow [this guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116914/magento-2-get-order-total-on-success-page) but I couldn't get it to work:

Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout/Success.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getGrandTotal()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->getLastOrderId());
        return $order->getGrandTotal();
    }
}
```

Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

```
$grandTotal = $block->getGrandTotal();
$grandTotal = number_format($grandTotal, 2, '.', '');
```

I get this error in magento_dir/var/log/system.log:

```
[2017-07-02 20:37:22] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'button.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'checkout.success.print.button' [] []
[2017-07-02 20:37:22] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'success.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'checkout.success' [] []
```

Is there a way to actually see the PHP error? /var/log/nginx/error.log doesn't show anything and neither does magento_dir/var/report/

Comment: please show your xml file where you have declared this phtml file defination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code.

step1 - app/code/Training/Grandtotalsuccesspage/registration.php.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,'Training_Grandtotalsuccesspage',__DIR__);
```

step2 - app/code/Training/Grandtotalsuccesspage/etc/module.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Training_Grandtotalsuccesspage" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

step3 - app/code/Training/Grandtotalsuccesspage/etc/di.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Training\Grandtotalsuccesspage\Block\Onepage\Success"/>
</config>
```

step4 - app/code/Training/Grandtotalsuccesspage/Block/Onepage/Success.php.

```
<?php

namespace Training\Grandtotalsuccesspage\Block\Onepage;

/**
 * One page checkout success page
 */
class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{

    protected $orderItemsDetails;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderItemsDetails
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderItemsDetails,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $checkoutSession, $orderConfig, $httpContext, $data);
        $this->orderItemsDetails = $orderItemsDetails;
    }

    public function getOrderItemsDetails()
    {
        $IncrementId  = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();
        $order_information = $this->orderItemsDetails->loadByIncrementId($IncrementId);
       return $order_information;
    }
}
```

step5 - app/code/Training/Grandtotalsuccesspage/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Success Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success.print.button" template="button.phtml"/>
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Thank you for your purchase!</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Training\Grandtotalsuccesspage\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success" template="success.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <container name="order.success.additional.info" label="Order Success Additional Info"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.registration" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

step6 - app/code/Training/Grandtotalsuccesspage/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml.

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrderItemsDetails(); ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
    <?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
            <p><?php echo __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
        <?php  else :?>
            <p><?php echo __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
            <p><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <a class="action primary continue" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl() ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$shipping_addresses = $_order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
$billing_addresses = $_order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
?>
<table>
    <tr><td>Shipping Address</td><td><?php print_r($shipping_addresses); ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Billing Address</td><td><?php print_r($billing_addresses); ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sub Total</td><td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getSubTotal()); ?></td>
    <tr><td>Shipping & Handling</td><td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getShippingAmount()); ?></td>
    <tr><td>Grand Total</td><td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()); ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

Run setup upgrade.

Run flush cache.

Give folder permission to var folder.

The output is look likes below screen shot.

[image]

You can download full package from github https://github.com/jothibasuj/M2--Order-success-page-customization

Comment: I have tried it, but for some reason the succes page is blank except for header and footer of the page. Also tried remove the function "getGrandTotal" and echo "$_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal());" to check if it at least completed the process with no luck.

Comment: @Cudos - please check the updated above code. let me know your feedback.

Comment: @Cudos - Did you check the above code?

Comment: Not yet, I will check it out as soon as I can, thank you a lot for your extensive example.

Comment: @Cudos - Gentle reminder - Did you check the above code?