# Order Total on Checkout Success page for Bing Ads - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, php, checkout

I'm trying to get just the order total on the checkout success page to be reported to Bing ads for a client.

In magento 1, this code is used in the **checkout/success.phtml** template:

```
<script>
<?php $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId); ?>

window.uetq = window.uetq || []; 
window.uetq.push({ 'gv': '<?php echo $order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>'}); 
</script>
```

**How can I accomplish this in Magento 2.1?**

also, is the path for this template different than magento 1?

> app/design/frontend/[theme]/template/checkout/success.phtml

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

```
<?php 
$lastOrderId = $this->getOrderId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($lastOrderId);
?>
<script>
window.uetq = window.uetq || []; 
window.uetq.push({ 'gv': '<?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?>'}); 
</script>
```

**Kindly note that I do not recommend using object manager like this directly. I insist please create your block and pass detail from there and you can retrieve in this file.**

Comment: Thank you! could you please elaborate on creating the block to pass the information? I'm a magento/php newbie.

Comment: How to create a custom module: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116914/magento-2-get-order-total-on-success-page/116922#116922