# Using object manager

Tags: magento2

I've question in the link below :
[Get grand total and customer data variables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358619/get-grand-total-and-customer-data-variables)

Now I solved the issue by using object manager directly, but I found too many people said it's not recommended !

Could you please tell me why ? also is there another way to use ?

Answer (score 1):

[**Dependency injection**](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/dependency-injection/)

If you wanted to load an order object using the order repository via the ObjectManager you would do something like:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderRepository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::class);
try {
    // Load order with entity_id 1
    $order = $orderRepository->get(1);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Order not found
}
// Do something with order object
```

However you *should* inject the OrderRepositoryInterface using constructor dependency injection like so:

```
private OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
) {
    $this->orderRepository = orderRepository;
)

public function someFunction()
{
    try {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get(1);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Order not loaded
    }
    // Do something with order object
}
```

There are several reasons you should do this:

- Enables you to write *testable* code, allowing you to pass *mock* objects into your class to run test cases with,
- It is also cleaner using DI as you do not need to get instances of the class yourself,
- It allows you to use Magento's `di.xml` to replace dependancies as required, for example a different areacode such as `webapi_rest` or `frontend` may benefit from a different class being injected in.

Comment: Hi Dear, Sorry I'm beginner in PHP. I've already created custom module, how I can use you solution with my module ?